# App was opened again from background after start activity from service

Tags: android

I have a Apple app which running background (press Home to hide it). It have a service running. That service will open other activity when internet was off. My problem was: if I'm opening Banana app and Apple app was running background (below Banana app) -> internet was off -> open Apple app despite I was opening Banana app.